# Can I turn on/off Android development mode programmatically?

Tags: android, development-mode

I cannot find any discussion about turn on/off Android development mode programmatically.

All the articles I found are talking about change it manually.

So I want to ask can I switch the development mode in program?

Comment: what would be the use case? What difference does it make if it is on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a regular device, with a regular app, you can't.

You need a rooted device or a signed APK in /system/app

Comment: Thanks, I give you the best answer since you were the earliest one.